# Where is the Mycelium wallet file stored?

Tags: backup, android, mycelium-wallet

I have a fairly straightforward question that's still unanswered after googling for days for a definite answer, I hope you guys can help me out with this one here.

**Background:** I have [Mycelium Bitcoin Wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycelium.wallet) installed on my Android phone [ROOT], I have backed up my [HD wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Deterministic_wallet) which also contains [Local Trader account](https://mycelium.com/lt/help.html), and have been successful in restoring said backup[s] (by means of un-installing app, wiping it's old data and re-installing / loading wallet from backup (Master seed)). I also have redundant backups of the app and it's data (I assume that includes the wallet file?) made with [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup).

**Question:** I however still do not know where Mycelium's wallet resides, is it on my SD extCard? SD Card? Data  partition? Protected Storage? Is it just determined by the Master Seed and hence resides nowhere?

**Final Note:** I'm eagerly awaiting this piece of information to be at ease with my policies, knowing that  I can manually backup/encrypt my wallet file (if there is one) is really important to me.

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Mycelium, the actual file that contains the encrypted keys are in the sqlite3 file. You can see in the source code that though there is in-memory storage, it's used mostly for testing and that the main way in which Mycelium data is stored is in a sqlite3 file. Sqlite, if you aren't familiar, is a very simple relational database that contains the whole database in a single file.

You can see the actual relational database table layout in [the source code](https://github.com/mycelium-com/wallet/blob/dbb7b5426114215d236df7534e1f3ab3252f82d4/public/mbw/src/main/java/com/mycelium/wallet/wapi/SqliteWalletManagerBacking.java).

To answer the question about exactly where the wallet is, mycelium does not have the installLocation attribute and therefore is only going to be stored in internal storage, or on the phone itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! Time to review that wallet handling code.

Comment: Thanks again, your answer proved most useful. Yes I'm used to work with SQL frameworks. Will wait a bit before I mark your answer as best, see if anybody else has anything to add.

Answer (score -1):

I was just looking for this very same information. My response is based on the current version of Mycelium (Sep 2016). This is what I found:

The backup is embedded in the 12 words Mycelium generates. So let's say you drop your phone in the ocean and get a new one. When you install the Mycelium app and restore the wallet, Mycelium will regenerate the wallet from those 12 words. Nothing is stored outside of the phone or on a server.

Comment: Does not answer the question -- this is about the actual wallet file.